# Why is the array correct, but not the count?

Tags: c, arrays

```
int arrays[100];
fseek(fp, 30, SEEK_SET);
fread(arrays, sizeof(int), 20, fp);
printf("%i\n", arrays);
int size = (sizeof(arrays)/ sizeof(int));
printf("There are %i numbers.", size); 

//Output:
//6421876
//There are 100 numbers
```

Clearly the array has 7 numbers in it, so why is it saying 100?

Comment: OT: `printf("%i\n", arrays);` you can not print an array using the integer format specifier, you need a loop and print `arrays[i]` on each iteration

Comment: Thank you for letting me know!

Comment: The `printf("%i\n", arrays);` just prints the address of the first element of the array. You should look into it to fully understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the array has 100 elements. You may have only written to some of them (20, assuming your `fread` worked okay) but that doesn't change the array size.

It's no different to pouring 250ml into a 1L jug. The *size* of the jug doesn't magically reduce by 75% just because it isn't full.

In any case, what you see as seven numbers (actually *one* number with seven digits) is nothing to do with what was written to the array. The expression `array` will, under most circumstances, decay to the address of the first element of that array. So the number you see is where the array is *located,* not what it holds.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in C are not dynamic. Your calculation of the array size is based on its static type. Its static type is, indeed, 100 elements.

If you want the system to keep track over how many elements there actually are, either write in another language, or explicitly keep a variable with this information.

Answer (score 0):

You say this line

```
printf("%i\n", arrays);
```

outputs `6421876` which you claim is 7 numbers, but it is not doing what you think. You are passing the *address* of `arrays` to the `printf` function and telling it that's an `int`, but the result is nothing useful.

Your calculation of array size, is the total number of elements in the array, not the number of elements actually read. If you want to know how many integers were read from the file, you must look at the return value from `fread` which tells you how many *items* were read from the file. You asked for `20` but the file may not have contained that many.

```
size_t ints_read = fread(arrays, sizeof(int), 20, fp);
```